# As much hated as much loved

Tags: meaning, adverbs, adverb-placement

I have a question about the following sentences concerning the word ***much***:

1. He is as hated as loved.
2. He is as ***much*** hated as loved.
3. He is as hated as ***much*** loved.
4. He is as ***much*** hated as ***much*** loved.

Do the use and non-use of word ***much*** make any differences?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they make a large difference. **Much** alone (as an adjective or adverb) means *great in degree*:

> How loved is he? He is **much** loved. How hated is he? He is **much** hated.

In contrast, **as much as** implies an equivalence or inequality:

> How much is he hated? He is hated [at least] **as much as** he is loved.

This sentence can be shortened to the equivalent

> He is **as much** hated as loved.

or the even shorter but less common

> He is as hated as loved.

Thus, 1 and 2 make sense, and 2 sounds more natural.

Answer (score 0):

He is as hated as loved.<sup>grammatical but "stilted" to my AmEar</sup>

He is as much hated as loved. <sup>idiomatic</sup>

He is as hated as much loved. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

He is as much hated as much loved. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: You could have 'he is as much hated as he is loved'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Sure. I'm just responding to OP's list.